# Can a non-admin add Entry types into a section?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, permissions, craft-pro

Is there a way to allow a user to edit sections without making them site Admins? For example, I have a couple of users that I want to allow them to create new entry types within a Channel, but I don’t want them to be able to access the rest of the Settings section of the CP or do everything an Admin can do.

I'm guessing this is something that will require a custom plugin, but is it possible to sidestep the admin permissions to create new entry types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to write a custom plugin that provided its own UI (outside of the Settings portion of the control panel) and that plugin's controller could mimic Craft's [SectionsController](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/SectionsController) (with the exception of not requiring an admin) while calling SectionsService's [saveEntryType](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/SectionsService#saveEntryType-detail).

For security your plugin should also register a custom "canSaveEntryType" [permission](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerUserPermissions) so you can have fine-grained control over who can call that method.